# How to Input and Output a file for Python with a Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have looked at other posts that are similar to my question, but still keep getting errors for my code.  I am supposed to take a file on my desktop with a list of fruit and bring it into python, have it sort itself and then create an output file.

I am told that there is a syntax error for outfile even though that is the code given to me by the teacher.  Does anyone know why my code wont work for me?

```
print "Program Started"

#Input and output file given
import os

infile = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt","r")
outfile = open("~/Desktop/sorted_fruits.txt","w")

#Reading of Input file
fruit=infile.read(50)

#Sorting of items in list
fruits.sort ()

for fruit in Fruits:
    if fruit <> "\n":       #If fruit is blank, skip the write
        outfile.write(fruit)    #otherwise write fruit to output file
        print (fruit)

#Closing of the input and output file
infile.close()
outfile.close()

print "Program Completed"
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Your code is a mess - you read the input file as `fruit`, then try to use the same variable name to iterate over `Fruits`, you use the deprecated `<>` operator, you import `os` for no reason...

Comment: I am just using the code given to me for the assignment.  This class has been a darn mess.  It is online which is enough said.  I can't get help from my teacher at all.

Comment: The error I am getting is a syntax one for outfile specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You had a few things wrong here, mostly syntax errors.
Specifically:

- `infile = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt","r")` is missing a `)` around `expanduser`
- outfile does not call `expanduser` and will not save properly
- `fruit=infile.read(50)` will just read it as a string, so sorting it as a list later won't work
- `for fruit in Fruits` - python is case sensitive, so Fruits needs to be fruits

---

Here's a working version

```
print "Program Started"

#Input and output file given
import os

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt"),"r") as infile:
    fruits = infile.read().splitlines()

outfile = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/sorted_fruits.txt"),"w")

#Reading of Input file
#fruits=infile.read(50)

#Sorting of items in list
fruits.sort()

for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit <> "\n":       #If fruit is blank, skip the write
        outfile.write(fruit)    #otherwise write fruit to output file
        print (fruit)

#Closing of the input and output file
#infile.close()
outfile.close()

print "Program Completed"
```

---

Just to caveat - *this is not good / clean code* - it just fixes the errors you had

Comment: Now I am getting an error for having as before infile.  Do you know why that would be?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about your error?  if you haven't fixed the closing `)` you will still get errors, that was the source of your first problem.  copy and paste the whole thing i provided there and it should work fine.

Comment: I am using IDLE and it says invalid syntax and highlights the as before infile, which I don't understand because you used it in the code you gave and another person used it so I am assuming it is a completely valid word to use in Python.

Comment: it should be totally fine, save it as a .py file and run it from the command line  `python myfile.py`.  you should be all good.

Comment: Also - for what it's work, I've found [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) to be a fantastic editor, much better than IDLE in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what error you are receiving or the structure of the file you are reading, I wrote this to generally show you what you should be doing.

```
#import os  -> imports should always go on top fyi

with open("~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt","r") as infile:
    sorted_file = sorted(infile.read().split())

with open("~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt","r") as outfile:
    for item in sorted_file:
        outfile.write(item)

print "Program Completed"
```

hope that helps a bit

Comment: I did what you wrote and this is the error I got.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shannongrice/Desktop/sort_fruits.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open("~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt","r") as Inputfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/unsorted_fruits.txt'     This is my code now:print "Program Started"

Comment: No such file of directory probably means you typed the path wrong.

Comment: Now it says I have an invalid syntax and highlights the as before infile.  Do you know why that would be?